# Passing input to ECS task from CloudWatch rule

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have requirement of scheduling ECS task with two Boolean variable as an input to it, I am aware of cloudWatch scheduling through cron expression but I cant pass input to ECS task, any suggestion if its doable without intermediate Lambda ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, and ended up naming my cloudwatch rules meaningfully, so I can derive info from the invoking cloudwatch rule. I then parse and extract fields from the name, and treat these as parameters to configure my task.

Comment: how can you tell which rule invokes the task within the task?